# GCP - retrieve cloud composer proxy url - throws error Expected OAuth 2 access toke

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, gcloud, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to get the cloud composer proxy url to trigger dags from cloud function. I am following below blog. however it's failing while retrieving this url.

https://medium.com/google-cloud/calling-cloud-composer-to-cloud-functions-and-back-again-securely-8e65d783acce

**Command**

```
curl -s  -H "Authorization: Bearer `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`" https://composer.googleapis.com/v1/projects/test/locations/us-east1/environments/test-environment
```

I tried `gcloud auth print-access-token` but same error

**error**

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "google.cloud.orchestration.airflow.service.v1.Environments.GetEnvironment",
          "service": "composer.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` works? If you manually include the returned token in the `curl` request, does it work? The error message indicates that there's no auth header included. Try the `curl` request with the `-v` option to verify if the header is being sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the medium post that you shared. NOTE (where my_project_id is, you have to set your project id).

First I created the project (My user has an owner role in the project) and the environment.

```
export GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID=`gcloud config get-value core/project`

export PROJECT_NUMBER=`gcloud projects describe my_project_id --format='value(projectNumber)'

gcloud composer environments create composer1  --location us-central1

gcloud composer environments  list --locations us-central1
```

After these steps I didn’t configure the `requirements.txt`. But I configured the connection.

```
gcloud composer environments update composer1  \
 --update-env-variables=AIRFLOW_CONN_MY_GCF_CONN=https://us-central1-my_project_id.cloudfunctions.net --location us-central1

gcloud composer environments describe composer1 --location us-central1

gcloud composer environments describe composer1 --location us-central1 --format="get(config.dagGcsPrefix)"
```

Then I went to Composer and I set the python packages manually.
[image]

You have to click on `EDIT` and add the name of the packages.
[image]

After the packages are installed you need to know if you have access to your token. **Here is some [documentation on how to create the a service account](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#creating_a_service_account). Then you need to set your credential in the terminal,command prompt or shell that you are using. And here is some [documentation on how to obtain the access token](https://medium.com/datamindedbe/three-methods-for-obtaining-gcp-access-tokens-7a516a79129a). You need to have a Service Account to have the token.**

Then I **follow step 3** where it brings you an error message.

```
curl -s  -H "Authorization: Bearer `gcloud auth print-access-token`" https://composer.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/my_project_id/locations/us-central1/environments/composer1 | jq [.config.airflowUri]
```

And this brings me, my URL for airflow that look like:

[

"https://url-tp.appspot.com"

]

Comment: even after installing all the packages. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you using Cloud Shell? What are the roles of your account in the project? Do you set the project [credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#creating_a_service_account)?

Comment: @GaurangShah I updated my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: it's my bad. I was using `cmd` to run the command where it was not able to convert ``` into code?